# Confused about how to wire headphone jack with a schematic

Tags: audio, schematics, led-driver

I've been trying to make an LED driver that responds to a signal sent over an audio cable and found this schematic:

[image: Schematic]

I'm pretty sure that the middle ring on the jack and socket (third contact) is the signal that goes to the capacitor but I'm confused about the ground "pin". I assume that it goes to the arrow at the bottom but I am new to this type of thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, the bottom of this circuit should be your ground, which is where the ground pin gets connected to.  Also, make sure you use the correct polarity on your input capacitor.

Comment: @mapplejacks - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However you answered the question in a comment, which is not an allowed use of comments (see the rules about comments [here](/help/privileges/comment) & [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)). Please avoid answering questions in comments in the future, as doing so causes various problems, as well as being against the site rules. Thanks. || The OP reports that your comment was a solution to their question - so, with appropriate attribution, it has been copied into an answer so that it can be treated as an answer.

Comment: captainretro - Hi, Please note that when a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference (source name & link) for that schematic & remember to include references in future. Thanks. || As you're new here, please see the main site rules in the [tour] & [help].

Comment: @SamGibson ah, good catch!  After rereading the rules, it's clear that even a trivial two-sentence response like this counts as an answer and not a clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Headphones with 3 pin TRS contacts are wired as follows:

- Tip: Left
- Ring: Right
- Sleeve: Ground (or common) for left and right.

Thus the Sleeve connects to the arrow at the bottom, the same net where the transistor Emitter is.

If you have headset jack with 4 pin TRRS contacts are more complicated, there's two pinouts, CTIA and OMTP. But both sockets should be compatible with 3-pin plug so it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

The OP, [captainretro](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/357384/captainretro), reports: "[mapplejacks](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/110234/mapplejacks) has answered my question in their [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/691782/confused-about-how-to-wire-headphone-jack-with-a-schematic/691839#comment1843347_691782)":

> Yes, the bottom of this circuit should be your ground, which is where the ground pin gets connected to. Also, make sure you use the correct polarity on your input capacitor.

---

<sub>(The solution was written as a comment, instead of an answer. Therefore the comment has been copied into this actual answer and I have applied the approach explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252303) to post someone else's content as an answer, with appropriate credit. The answer has been set to "Community wiki" so that I don't earn any points from upvotes on this answer, as it isn't *my* solution.)</sub>